# How not to display a container if user is logged off?

Tags: php, styles, containers

I have a container created in style.css file.
And, how can i display a container if user is logged in and don't if he's not logged in ?

**CODE:**

```
<div class="container">

<?php
if($_SESSION['id'])
echo '<center>TURINYS MATOMAS TIK NARIAMS</center>';
?>
</div>
```

Now here, if user is logged in, it displays text "TURINYS MATOMAS TIK NARIAMS", but if user is not logged in it just displays a blank container

Comment: Why not move the `<div>` inside the `if` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test the code, but this should work:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['id']) : ?>

  <div class="container">
    <center><?php echo 'TURINYS MATOMAS TIK NARIAMS'; ?> </center>
  </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){ ?>
  <div class="container">
    <center>
        <?php echo 'TURINYS MATOMAS TIK NARIAMS'; ?> 
    </center>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```